# How to select nth and (n+1)th word from string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select third and fourth word from a string in SQL Server.

This is what I tried:

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(100) = 'get 3rd and 4th word from this';

SELECT Word
FROM
    (
     SELECT Value AS Word,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
     FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Var, ' ')
    ) T
WHERE RN >= 3 AND RN <=4;
```

But the issue is `STRING_SPLIT` is not supported in my database.

Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` is supported from SQL Server **2016** on - so the easiest "workaround" is to just simply upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server ...

Comment: production db is not in my control @marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string splitter that supports ordinal position (`STRING_SPLIT` does not), such as [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) and this is trvial:

```sql
SELECT item
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD('get 3rd and 4th word from this',' ') DS
WHERE DS.itemnumber IN (3,4);
```

Comment: this is returning the same error @Larnu Invalid object name 'dbo.DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD'.

Comment: Have you created the function, @MohdMaaz ? The errors suggests not.